# IDOR or something else?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability

While analyzing a web application, I identified a path of the type `https://example/remove/123`, which allows a user with lower privileges to remove a report created by a user with higher privileges. In theory, the user with lower privileges shouldn't even be able to view this report, but in reality, they can even delete it by knowing the appropriate ID and path. That said, can this issue be included in IDOR, or should I break it down into two vulnerabilities, such as IDOR and broken access control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classifying vulnerabilities gets weird sometimes, but in this case I think it's pretty straightforward. This is definitely broken/missing authorization (access control). As a category that *includes* IDOR, but whether this is centrally IDOR mostly depends on whether you can insecurely directly access/reference the objects (reports) in other ways (e.g. to read, edit, whatever). If you can't, especially if you can't *even at other endpoints that look similar* including the identifier, then it's probably just a flaw in that one endpoint rather than in the security model of the app as a whole. That doesn't mean it's *not* IDOR - you are still directly referring to the object in a way that isn't secured - but it might cause more confusion if classed that way.

The thing to remember here is that vulnerability classifications really only serve two purposes: they help people understand where the problem likely is, and they help people remember or look up what remedies to apply. Remediating IDOR is just a special case of remediating broken authz - you go to the place that should be performing an authz check and either add one or fix the broken one - but for IDOR in particular the implication is that the access checks exist (or should exist) on the object, often (though not always) via some sort of ACL mechanism. If that ACL is allowing Delete permission to to Everyone (or something like that), then that's more centrally IDOR. If each endpoint instead has its own checks and they just forgot to include them on /remove, that's less centrally IDOR.

If you already have a finding for IDOR but it's a different kind of access and/or especially if it happens on different objects, I'd make this one its own finding classed as broken authz. If you have a finding for IDOR on the report objects via some other endpoint, it might make sense to fold this finding into that one, because the common connection is probably the report object. If you don't have an IDOR finding yet at all, but the rest of the app doesn't seem to have any permission problems and there's no obvious interface for controlling things like "who is allowed to delete this report", then I might *mention* IDOR in the finding but I wouldn't classify it *as* IDOR unless that's for some reason a thing that the client specifically cares about. I would *not* list two vulnerabilities for this issue; it's almost certainly only a single problem and only needs one remediation and probably doesn't directly manifest any other unexpected behavior such that multiple categorizations would make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

> In theory, the user with lower privileges shouldn't even be able to view this report, but in reality, they can even delete it by knowing the appropriate ID and path.

My next step at this point would be to try and dig into this a bit more, and in particular to determine whether there is meant to be *object level* access control here. That is, are there high privileged users who have the ability to delete some reports, but not others? Or is it intended that any high privileged user can delete any report?

Id it's the former, then this is both an *object level* access control issue (because your low privileged user can delete reports that aren't linked to them), and a *function level* access control issue (because they can access the "delete report" functionality at all).

If it's the latter, then this is just a *function level* access control issue, and there is (by design) no *object level* access control on this function.

---

In either case it's ultimately broken access control, and probably makes sense to report as a single issue. But it's often useful to think about whether it's an *object level* or *function level* issue (or both).

Comment: Thanks @Gh0stFish, after what I have read I also think that it is appropriate to report it as the only vulnerability and specifically a broken access control.